# How to avoid `missing type` error while chaining partial functions

Tags: scala, akka, anonymous-function, partialfunction

I'm currently studying Scala & Akka and developing test application for it. In this application almost all actors log unhandled messages for ease of debug:

```scala
import akka.actor._

class TestActor extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  def receive: Receive = {
    case Some(value) => // do something...
    case msg => log.debug("Unhandled message: {}.", msg)
  }
}
```

As I said, such code exists almost in all of my agents and I started to think about moving it into a trait:

```scala
trait LogUnhandled { this: Actor with ActorLogging =>
  def logUnhandled: Receive = {
    case msg => log.debug("Unhandled message: {}.", msg)
  }
}
```

and using it after like

```scala
class TestActor extends Actor with ActorLogging with LogUnhandled {
  def receive: Receive = {
    case Some(value) => // do something...
  } orElse logUnhandled
}
```

I was wondering mostly if structural subtyping will allow me do that or `TestActor#Receive` and `LogUnhadled#Receive` would be different types, but even before that I've got

```
error: missing parameter type for expanded function
The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5)
Expected type was: ?
```

And for now I could not figure how to avoid this other than by moving first `{...}` block into separate function:

```scala
class TestActor extends Actor with ActorLogging with LogUnhandled {
  def doReceive: Receive = {
    case Some(value) => // do something...
  } 

  def receive: Receive = doReceive orElse logUnhandled
}
```

Latter will do, of course, but it is kinda 'missing the point' and inflicts some other side effects like 'think about appropriate function name instead of `receive`'...

So I wonder: is it possible to avoid 'missing type parameter error' by somehow declaring `(Any) => Unit` function signature 'in place'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class TestActor extends Actor with ActorLogging with LogUnhandled {
  def receive = ({
    case Some(value) => // do something...
  }: Receive) orElse logUnhandled
}
```

Also take a look at [this](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/event/LoggingReceive.scala). LoggingReceive lets you do sth like the following:

```
class A extends Actor {
   def receive = LoggingReceive {
      case msg => ...
   }
}
```

And all accepted/rejected messages are going to be published to the debug stream.

Comment: Thank you! This exactly what I needed. And with this switchable `LoggingReceive` it would be even better.